# What does a function object look like if it has a number of parameters?

Tags: c++

I have created a very simple `Tree` implementation, and I would like to be able to pass a function object to my `traverse()` function. e.g.

```
template<class T>
class MyTree
{
public:

    void traverse(MyFunction f) {
        traverse(root, f);
    }
private:
      MyTreeNode<T>* root;
      void traverse(MyTreeNode<T>*, MyFunction f);
};
```

The thing is, how do I declare `f` if I want to pass in some parameters as well as the node in question? ( pointers to other `structs` ). Alternatively, can anyone point me in the direction of some tutorials?

Comment: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=141

Comment: Is it how do I declare 'f' or how do I declare 'MyFunction'?

Comment: @Chubsdad, it's how do I declare 'MyFunction'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things that you can do at this stage.

The old style C type solution: you can pass a function pointer:

```
template <typename T>
void MyTree<T>::traverse( void (*function)( MyTreeNode<T>*, int ) );
```

That will take as argument a function pointer (free function) that takes a pointer to a `MyTreeNode<T>` object as first argument and an integer as second argument. And you can `typedef` the function type to ease usage:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTree {
public:
   typedef void func( MyTreenode<T>*, int );     // typedef the function type
   typedef void (*pfunc)( MyTreenode<T>*, int ); // or the function pointer
   void traverse( func* function );
   void traverse2( pfunc function );
};
```

You can take any callable *thing* as argument with the help of a template:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTree {
public:
   template <typename Functor> 
   void traverse( Functor f );
};
```

Which in the simplest approach is *simple* if you leave the argument types free, but the error messages if you try to pass a callable entity that takes a different set of arguments may not be so simple to parse. Internally you can use `f` as if it were a function, but externally can be either a function or function objects, including the result of `std::bind` (c++0x) or `boost::bind`

You can go one step forward and actually enforce in the signature of the `traverse` function the arguments you are going to use by using `std::function` (again, c++0x) or `boost::function`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTree {
public:
   void traverse( std::function< void (MyTreeNode<T>*, int )> f );
};
```

The advantage of this solution is that it is clear how you are going to use the passed in parameter (as in the function pointer approach): you will call `f( x, y )` where `x` is a `MyTreeNode<T>*` and `y` is an integer. At the same time you provide the genericity of the templated solution by means of `std::bind` (c++0x) or `boost::bind`, that can be used to adapt different entities to the `function<...>` argument, including free functions, function objects, member functions...

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use `boost::function` and define a function type which only takes your node as parameter. Then, you can create a `boost::function` object from whatever function you like as long as you bind the additional parameters.

```
template<class T>
class MyTree
{
public:
    typedef boost::function< void (MyTreeNode<T>*) > MyFunction;

    void traverse(MyFunction f) {
        traverse(root, f);
    }
private:
      MyTreeNode<T>* root;
      void traverse(MyTreeNode<T>*, MyFunction f);
};

tree.traverse( boost::bind( &func_with_args, _1, arg1, arg2 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a template member function,

```
template<class T>
class MyTree
{
public:

    template<typename Functor>
    void traverse(Functor f) {
        traverse(root, f);
    }
private:
      MyTreeNode<T>* root;

      template<typename Functor>
      void traverse(MyTreeNode<T>* node, Functor f) {
         f(node->value);
         // etc...
      }
};
```

In this form, any function objects that can be called as `f(x)` will be accepted.

Comment: where should I declare Functor? What would it look like if it has extra parameters?

Comment: @BeeBand: There's no need to declare Functor because it is a template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you are asking about how a functor is declared. Here is a small code that should give you the idea.

```
struct A{
 void operator()(int x, double d){}   // overloaded operator()
};

int main(){
 A a;
 a(2, 3.0);
}
```